# Stats, Independence question using deck of cards

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics

thank you for your time. This is my assignment question so please dont answer it for me, but I am looking for any tips that would help me solve this question.

The question

Suppose that two cards are drawen simultaneously from a standard 52-card poker deck. Let $A$ be the event that both are either jack, queen, king or ace of hearts, and let $B$ be the event that both are aces. Are $A$ and $B$ indepedent?

My solution so far

Notice that there is $\binom{52}{2} = 1326$ different ways to choose 2 cards simultaneously from a standard 52-card deck. For event $A$, we have $P(A) = \binom{4}{2}/\binom{52}{2} = 1/221$ where $\binom{4}{2}$ is the number of ways to choose 2 cards that are either jack, queen or ace of hearts. We also have $P(B) = \binom{4}{2}/\binom{52}{2} = 1/221$ where $\binom{4}{2}$ is the number of ways of choosing 2 cards that are aces.

My question

I am sure that $A$ and $B$ are not independent but I don't know how to go forth. I am just confused on how I can get $P(A\cap B)$ (this will help me show that $P(A\cap B) \neq P(A)P(B)$). I know that there is $6$ different ways to get the result needed in event $A$ and there is $6$ different ways to get the result in event $B$, out of each, in event $A$, we know that 3 of the 6 options will contain ace of hearts and for $B$, 3 out of the 6 will also contain 3 options with ace of hearts. Then we know the intersection will have 3 elements. Then would it be correct to say that there is $P(A \cap B) = 3/1326$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that I told you that the two cards were both either the jack, queen, king or ace of hearts. What is the probability that they're also both aces?

Comment: I think that would be 0. Then the events are not intersecting ?

Comment: Yep, and that's essentially your answer

Comment: Thank you I think I might have overlooked the question

Comment: No problem at all!